# Beautiful Soup to parse url to get another urls data

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to parse a url to get a list of urls that link to a detail page. Then from that page I need to get all the details from that page. I need to do it this way because the detail page url is not regularly incremented and changes, but the event list page stays the same.

Basically:

```
example.com/events/
    <a href="http://example.com/events/1">Event 1</a>
    <a href="http://example.com/events/2">Event 2</a>

example.com/events/1
    ...some detail stuff I need

example.com/events/2
    ...some detail stuff I need
```

Comment: What did you try, and why did that not work?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet. I know how to parse the detail page, but not how to get to the data via the list page.

Comment: Yeah, well, it's a nice touch if you read the docs and at least make an effort first, IMO.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://yahoo.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    print anchor['href']
```

It will give you the list of urls. Now You can iterate over those urls and parse the data.

- `inner_div = soup.findAll("div", {"id": "y-shade"})` 
  This is an example. You can go through the BeautifulSoup tutorials.

Comment: This looks like it will work. Can you narrow the results to a specific div or ul?

Comment: yes..You can specify div. For this You can use the class. I am updating my answer in a while.

Comment: Can you elaborate what for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True): does?

Comment: Find all tag with an href. Actually soup.findAll('a', href=True) is same as soup.findAll(href=True) in the above case. In latest version findAll has been replaced by find_all.

Comment: For  Pyhon3, it's : ```from urllib.request import urlopen``` and     ```from bs4 import BeautifulSoup```

Answer (score 9):

For the next group of people that come across this, BeautifulSoup has been upgraded to v4 as of this post as v3 is no longer being updated..

```
$ easy_install beautifulsoup4

$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

To use in Python...

```
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: I also now recommend using Python requests over urllib2.  Yes, it's a non-core module but you will save yourself so much headache by using it.  It was proposed to become part of core but ultimately decided against it.

Short Intro - https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/1872970

docs - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 5):

Use urllib2 to get the page, then use beautiful soup to get the list of links, also try scraperwiki.com

Edit:

Recent discovery: Using BeautifulSoup through lxml with

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
```

is miles better than just BeautifulSoup. It lets you do dom.cssselect('your selector') which is a life saver. Just make sure you have a good version of BeautifulSoup installed. 3.2.1 works a treat.

```
dom = fromstring('<html... ...')
navigation_links = [a.get('href') for a in htm.cssselect('#navigation a')]
```

Answer (score 4):

**FULL PYTHON 3 EXAMPLE**

Packages

```
# urllib (comes with standard python distribution)
# pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Example:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.wikipedia.org/') as f:
    data = f.read().decode('utf-8')

d = BeautifulSoup(data)

d.title.string
```

The above should print out `'Wikipedia'`

Comment: hi  there - many thahnks for sharing this -  this is just awesome! i am glad that you have provided the python3 version here.!!!

Comment: doesn't `urllib` come with the standard lib?, Also, the import should be just `import urllib`, no?