# Extract social links from any website in python BeautifulSoup or selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I want an automated python program to fetch particular website's social media (LinkedIn link) present in that website. Link may after be changed to another website but program must be independent of link-changine and should fetch linkedIn link (if available)for every website link.
In summary: I want a generic python program to fetch social media links for the given website url.
Thanks

Waiting for your help and kind response. –
I tried alot but couldn't find out the way.
@poojan please help......
Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code. We will help you making your program work, but not writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linkedin

```
for link in links:
    if "linkedin" in link:
        print("We found a linked in Link")
```

In general with a list of names:

```
sn_links = ["facebook"] # etc.
for link in links:
    for social in sn_links:
        if social in link:
            print("We found a social Link")
```

Comment: Thank You So Much, But i want this code in BeautifulSoup since i work in whole project in BeautifulSoup

Comment: @ÂftãbBãlôçh You could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4462877/12846952) to create the list of links. Then you can use my code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to you

From this you can find all the links

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en')

# here you can find all the links
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
time.sleep(3)

# printing how many links are there
print(len(links))

# printing the link text using for loop
for link in links:
        print(link.text)

# if you want you can use if statements to check whether they are social media links or not
```

Hope you got it

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the tricky part is that to compare either it is a social media link or not. Since every website has different variables to store social media links. Can you please share the comparison code ? So that i may have a little bit idea how do we compare.